# How to fix " Unable to get property 'get' of undefined or null reference "

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

I'm trying to create application. However I keep getting error saying "Unable to get property 'get' of undefined or null reference at  ProfilePage.prototype.ngOnInit".

I'm using ionic 4 as my framework. This error occur when I was trying to navigate from my home page to my profile page

```
HomePage.html:
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
      <ion-buttons slot="end">
        <ion-button routerLink="/profile">
          <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="person"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
      </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

```
profile.page.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/user/auth.service';
import { ProfileService } from '../../services/user/profile.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.page.scss']
})
export class ProfilePage implements OnInit {
  public userProfile: any;
  public birthDate: Date;
  constructor(
    private alertCtrl: AlertController,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private profileService: ProfileService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.profileService
      .getUserProfile()
      .get()
      .then(userProfileSnapshot => {
        this.userProfile = userProfileSnapshot.data();
        this.birthDate = userProfileSnapshot.data().birthDate;
      });
  }
......
```

```
Homepage.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

The code above is expected to allow user to go to profile page. however the result were "Unable to get property 'get' of undefined or null reference at  ProfilePage.prototype.ngOnInit"

Comment: The problem here is getUserProfile() returns null or undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
ngOnInit() {

if(this.profileService.getUserProfile() {
    this.profileService
      .getUserProfile()
      .get()
      .then(userProfileSnapshot => {
        this.userProfile = userProfileSnapshot.data();
        this.birthDate = userProfileSnapshot.data().birthDate;
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probable your `this.profileService.getUserProfile()` just returns null or undefined. Check it using chrome dev tools Source tab (search your file using ctrl (cmd) + p)